# Additional static IPv6 address on Ubuntu 14

Tags: linux-networking, ipv6

My ISP gave me a /64 IPv6 subnet, so I'm trying to add a static IPv6 address on top of the one that is already configured in my Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.
So far, all my attempts failed and I don't know where to look for information.

I did all tests by editing

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

then issuing a

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

I checked the new address with

```
ip -6 addr
```

and

```
ping6 <newAddress>
```

but it always failed to work (not shown / not responding).

The original content of /etc/network/interfaces is the following (addresses masked with ***:*** for privacy):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto  eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address   85.10.***.***
  netmask   255.255.255.224
  gateway   85.10.***.***
  up route add -net 85.10.***.*** netmask 255.255.255.224 gw 85.10.***.*** eth0

iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 2a01:4f8:***:***::2
  netmask 64
  gateway fe80::1
```

During my attempts at adding 2a01:4f8:xxx:xxx::3 I appended the following to the bottom of the file (in each test removing what was added by the previous one):

**Test 1**

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
        address  2a01:4f8:***:***::3
        netmask 64
```

**Test 2**

```
up /sbin/ifconfig eth0 inet6 add 2a01:4f8:***:***::3/64
```

**Test 3**

```
up ip -6 addr add 2a01:4f8:***:***::3 dev eth0
```

I found them around the web and in other answers, but none worked.

```
ping6 2a01:4f8:***:***::3
PING 2a01:4f8:***:***::3(2a01:4f8:***:***::3) 56 data bytes
From 2a01:4f8:***:***::2 icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```

Am I missing something?

What is the correct syntax for my system?

Where is the documentation for this?

Comment: I just found out that "ip addr add  2a01:4f8:***:***::3 dev eth0" works in the shell but not in the interfaces file (preceding it by "up")

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
up ip -6 addr add 2a01:4f8:***:***::3/64 dev eth0
```

I'm surprised gateway fe80::1 worked without a trailing %eth0.
I'm not sure I understand how your /64 is routed to you.

Answer (score -1):

If you want more then one ip[6] address you this syntax in your /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 2a01:4f8:***:***::2
  netmask 64

auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet6 static
  address 2a01:4f8:***:***::3
  netmask 64
```

After `ifup eth0:2` or restarting networking you can check with `ip -6 addr show dev eth0` if your interface have this two adresses

Comment: The ancient `eth0:2` alias format is not used anymore for IPv4, and was never used for IPv6. This should say `eth0`, not `eth0:2`.